# TFS Express 2012 build failing

Tags: tfs, msbuild, access-denied

I have a VS solution hosted in a TFS 2012 Express with a Build system (service, controller, agent) in place. I also created a build definition with this build project file as target:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0"
         DefaultTargets="Build"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutDir Condition=" '$(OutDir)'=='' ">$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)bin\</OutDir>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)'=='' ">Release</Configuration>
    <SourceHome Condition=" '$(SourceHome)'=='' ">$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)</SourceHome>
    <ToolsHome Condition=" '$(ToolsHome)'=='' ">$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)tools\</ToolsHome>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Solution Include="$(SourceHome)*.sln">
      <AdditionalProperties>OutDir=$(OutDir);Configuration=$(Configuration)</AdditionalProperties>
    </Solution>
  </ItemGroup>

  <Target Name="RestorePackages">
    <Exec Command="&quot;$(MSBuildProgramFiles32)\NuGet\NuGet.exe&quot; config -set http_proxy=http://********" />
    <Exec Command="&quot;$(MSBuildProgramFiles32)\NuGet\NuGet.exe&quot; config -set http_proxy.user=******" />
    <Exec Command="&quot;$(MSBuildProgramFiles32)\NuGet\NuGet.exe&quot; config -set http_proxy.password=********" />
    <Exec Command="&quot;$(MSBuildProgramFiles32)\NuGet\NuGet.exe&quot; restore &quot;$(SourceHome)*.sln&quot;" />
  </Target>

  <Target Name="Clean">
    <MSBuild Targets="Clean"
             Projects="@(Solution)" />
  </Target>

  <Target Name="Build" DependsOnTargets="RestorePackages">
    <MSBuild Targets="Build"
             Projects="@(Solution)" />
  </Target>

  <Target Name="Rebuild" DependsOnTargets="RestorePackages">
    <MSBuild Targets="Rebuild"
             Projects="@(Solution)" />
  </Target>

</Project>
```

But somehow the build keeps failing again and again. This is the error:

```
Exception Message: Access to the path '******************\packages\AjaxControlToolkit.15.1.4.0\Content\Web.config.transform' is denied. (type UnauthorizedAccessException).
```

I have no clue what's going on, any ideas?

Comment: Whats your source path on the build? Solution directory or project directory?

Comment: The source control folder was pointing to the project folder. I changed it to the solution and folder and the error has changed to the following:
 Exception Message: Access to the path '*************\bin\mscorlib.dll is denied

Comment: Do other builds work successfully?  Has this worked in the past?  Does the build agent user account have access to these paths?

Comment: No, so far I've been unable to make any build work for this solution. I granted permissions to the NETWORK SERVICE account on the folder, and now the errors I'm getting are related to nuget. Somehow the package restoration stated in the build.proj posted above is is not working. However I was able to restore packages manually via command line. Can't figure out what I'm missing here...

Comment: Try running the agent as an admin user or a user with more rights.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end the issue was the NETWORK SERVICE account used for the build service. That account does not seem to have enough privileges to use the proxy. Changed it to my account finally worked. I know it's not the ideal approach, but does the trick for now.

Answer (score 0):

You may check whether the files are read-only.